# TableView Pagination with swift and parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pagination

I have been searched by a method to do pagination with swift and parse (parse.com) and don't found what i wish, so worked on a solution and would like to share it. Its tested and working on today 09/22/2015 with Xcode 7, iOS9 and parse library 1.8.2:

In this type of pagination all data are stored in `tableDataArray` and never is deleted. When is no more data to download the variable `tableDataArray` keeps your size fixed.

First define those property's on your `ViewController Class`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

var tableDataArray = [String]()

var countPage = 0    //number of current page

var stepPage = 50    //number of records by page

var maxRow = 0       //maximum limit records of your parse table class

var maxPage = 0      //maximum page

//Start the process to load the data
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    self.tableDataArray.removeAll()

    getLimitRecordFromTable("parseClassName")
}
```

Override or declare this function of `TableView Protocol`:

```
//Pagination
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let row = indexPath.row

    let lastRow = self.tableGamesArray.count - 1

    let pageLimit = (((self.countPage+1) * (self.stepPage)) - 1)  //prevision of the page limit based on step and countPage

    //Only for debug
    print("\(row) from [0,\(lastRow)] -> limit: \(pageLimit)")

    // 1) The last rown and is the last
    // 2) To avoid two calls in a short space from time, while the data is downloading
    // 3) The current array count is smaller than the maximum limit from database
    if (row == lastRow) && (row == pageLimit) && (self.tableGamesArray.count < self.maxRow)
    {
        self.countPage++

        print("Loading Page \(self.countPage) from \(self.maxPage)")

        self.loadGamesFromCloudDataStore(false)

        self.myTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Get the maximum limit records of your parse table class:

```
func getLimitRecordFromTable(parseClassName: String)
{
    let queryLocal = PFQuery(className: parseClassName)
    queryLocal.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(
    {
        (countLocal: Int32, errorLocal: NSError?) -> Void in

        if( errorLocal == nil)
        {
            self.maxRow = Int(countLocal) //Limit for pagination

            self.maxPage = Int(self.maxRow/self.stepPage) + 1

            self.loadGamesFromCloudDataStore()
        }
    })
}
```

Load the games from parse data cloud store:

```
func loadGamesFromCloudDataStore(parseClassName: String)
{
    let query = PFQuery(className: parseClassName)

    //Pagination
    query.limit = self.stepPage
    if( self.countPage > 0 )
    {
        query.skip = self.countPage * self.stepPage
    }

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(
    {
        (objects, error) -> Void in

        if let objects = objects
        {
            for object in objects
            {
                let id = object.objectId as String!

                self.tableDataArray.append(id)
            }
            self.myTableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: tried it but don't work, I got infinite loading

Comment: Do you all realize that the PFQueryTableViewController in Parse has built in support for pagination and pull to refresh? It's as easy as setting the number of objects per page.